# Writing c++ "array" class myself

Tags: c++, class, object, compiler-errors

I am writing c++ integer array class myself and a function for extracting sub-arrays but I am getting this error while trying to compile my code:

"Multiple markers at this line
- No return, in function returning non-void
- with ‘Array Array::subArr(int, int)’"

(sorry forgot to include this error)

```
- ‘int* Array::subArr(int, int)’ cannot be overloaded
```

But why cant it be overloaded?

The private data members of class Array are:

```
private:
    int *arr;
    int *subArray;
    int *subArr1;
    int len;
```

The two public functions causing the error are:

```
int * subArr(int pos, int siz)
{
    if (pos+siz < len)
    {
        subArr1 = new int[siz];
        for (int i=0; i<siz; i++)
        {
            subArr1[i] = arr[pos];
            pos++;
        }
        return subArr1;
    }
}
```

and

```
Array subArr(int pos, int siz)
{
    if (arr != NULL && (siz + pos) < len)
    {
        Array sub;
        sub.len = siz;
        sub.subArray = new int [siz];
        for (int i=0; i<siz; i++)
        {
            sub.subArray[i] = arr[pos];
            pos++;
        }
        return sub;
    }
    cout<<"Error. Enter a valid index and/or position\n";
}
```

I can send the whole class code if it is required.

Comment: Well, what's unclear about the error message? Outside the `if` block there's no `return`.

Comment: the error message is actually quite clear, your function is supposed to return an `int *`, but for some cases it does not.

Comment: Did you read what the Compiler says? It says your function does not return a value. And clearly there are code pathes (`else` because your `if` is not fulfilled) where the function does not have a return.

Comment: Thanks and kindly check the question again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just what it says;

> No return, in function returning non-void - with ‘Array Array::subArr(int, int)’"

Look at the code:

```
int * subArr(int pos, int siz)
{
    if (pos+siz < len)
    {
        subArr1 = new int[siz];
        for (int i=0; i<siz; i++)
        {
            subArr1[i] = arr[pos];
            pos++;
        }
        return subArr1;
    }
}
```

What happens if the `if (pos+siz < len)` is false?

Correct, you don't have anything to return, in a function declared to return `int *`. That's an error.

---

> ‘int* Array::subArr(int, int)’ cannot be overloaded

Look at the code:

```
int * subArr(int pos, int siz)
Array subArr(int pos, int siz)
```

The two functions differ only in return type. That is not possible; there must be a difference in the number and / or the type of the parameters.

---

Gratuitous generic advice:

- Avoid reimplementing standard functionality, other than as exercise.
- Avoid using pointers.
- Avoid `new` unless...

  - in a constructor where your destructor has the corresponding `delete`.
  - wrapped in a smart pointer allocation.

  (Allocating memory inside a function and then expecting the caller to free it again is a prime source for memory leaks.)
- Don't write errors to `cout`, throw an exception.
- Use nullptr, not NULL.

In short, write C++, not C with classes -- that was thirty years ago.

Comment: Thanks Sir but kindly check the above question again

Comment: @AbdulMateen: Adding to the gratuitous generic advice: Don't change the question after posting it. Amended my answer to cover the added question.

Comment: @AbdulMateen: One more -- [get a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/). No, really. ;-)

Comment: Thanks you for your kind help and advice. I'll surely try to follow these. Sorry for my mistakes (I will try to improve)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reach the end of your functions and you do not return anything at the end.  If you have a function that is suposed to return something then every path out of the function needs to have a return.  Basically

```
int * subArr(int pos, int siz)
{
    if (pos+siz < len)
    {
        subArr1 = new int[siz];
        for (int i=0; i<siz; i++)
        {
            subArr1[i] = arr[pos];
            pos++;
        }
        return subArr1;
    }
}
```

Becomes

```
int * subArr(int pos, int siz)
{

}
```

if `if (pos+siz < len)` is false.  Since there is no return you get the error.

---

You second issue is you cannot overload a function based on its return type alone.

```
Array subArr(int pos, int siz)
int * subArr(int pos, int siz)
```

Ignoring the return type on the function we have

```
subArr(int pos, int siz)
subArr(int pos, int siz)
```

How is it supposed to tell them apart?  It can't.  That is why it is not allowed.

Comment: kindly check the question again Sir

Comment: So it means that overloading depends upon the data type of arguments and not return type?

Comment: @AbdulMateen Kindly ask the correct question.  It is not polite to chamnge your question after you get an answer.  I have updated.